# Graphic tool to display element tree branch in git for linux

Tags: git, clearcase, tortoisegit

Having used clearcase lsvtree for many years I miss that functionality in git. Anybody know about a similar tool for linux? gitk is not as friendly for big trees and Tortoisegit looks cool but does not support linux. 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a project (that I haven't tested recently) to transform a gitk log into a version tree:

[**crc8/GitVersionTree**](https://github.com/crc8/GitVersionTree)

To go from:

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/24c10f4b548816935b7145b77d205458255eb0bd/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f637263382f47697456657273696f6e547265652f6d61737465722f73616d706c655f6769746b2e706e67]

to:

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/0cf835a38473b6caa9b39fe59a7088d3dcb70f09/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f637263382f47697456657273696f6e547265652f6d61737465722f73616d706c655f6776742e706e67]

This is the closest I have seen from a ClearCase version tree.

Comment: looks interesting but it only supports Windows, same for Tortoisegit. I was looking for something that runs in Linux. thanks