# Display ASCII graph of Cleartool ls commands

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

In git it is possible to show an ASCII graph of the log with `git log --graph` which outputs a commandline graph something like:

```
* 040cc7c       (HEAD, master) Mannual is NOT built by default
* a29ceb7       Removed offensive binary file that was compiled on my machine
| * 901c7dd     (cvc3) cvc3 now configured before building
| * d9e8b5e     More sane Yices SMT solver caller
| | * 5b98a10   (nullvars) All uninitialized variables get zero inits
| |/
| * 1cad874     CFLAGS for cvc3 to work succesfully
|/
* d642f88       Option -aliasstat, by default stats are suppressed
```

- Is this also possible with ClearCase / ClearTool when using the `lsstream` or  `lsvtree` commands, without the need to open a GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I couldn't find anything that suited me, I created my own python script with this ability. It is still a little rough, but works for me.

For anyone interested, it is available [here as a github gist](https://gist.github.com/spoorcc/ef07e09484bb8d3b3c5f)

Comment: Interesting, more suited to your need than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

With command line, you have [`cleartool lsvtree`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-1-29).

If you want the history to focus on the branch you currently are (instead of starting by default at `/main`), you need to use the `-bra/nch branch-pname` option.

> Starts the version tree listing at the specified branch.
>   You can also use an extended name as the pname argument (for example, `foo.c@@\main\bug405`) to start the listing at a particular branch.

But if you need additional information like the author, then you would need to fallback to [`cleartool lshistory`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-25&lang=en): see "[How to ask cleartool `lsvtree` to show the author's name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28944051/6309)"

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I'm specifically looking for the ASCII graph  , to get a kind of visual reference.

Comment: @user1149326 ClearCase has not the notion of ACL graph, only one of a tree. So lsvtree is all you can get.

Comment: @user1149326 acutally, you would find the opposite request (transform a git acl history into a lsvtree one!): http://stackoverflow.com/q/26680543/6309

Comment: The lsvtree meant there is I guess the GUI version `cleartool lsvtree -g <filename>`, which gives a graphical representation of what I want, but I would like that output to be ASCII based with the same lines representing the rebases/deliveries/merges.

Comment: @user1149326 I don't know that cleartool lsvtree does that. It only display a list of versions: `cleartool lsvtree -all <filename>`